# Failed to download packages from software center

Tags: package-management, downloads, vlc

I tried to install many softwares from software center like VLC, Quickly etc but failed to download and install them on my Ubuntu. It gave this error. Failed to download package.
Please help me.

Comment: If its a fresh install then you'd better first run sudo apt-get update then you can installation of the software. If you still getting the same errors then edit your question and paste those error reports . so that we can help you to resolve that issue.

Comment: This error happens when I try to install any package..

Failed to fetch http://stingray.cyber.net.pk/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sidplay-libs/libsidplay2_2.1.1-13_i386.deb  403  Forbidden
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

After then when I try sudo apt-get update
and then try to install again then it shows the same error

Comment: It's saying to do sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: I tried to install many packages but it gave me same error "Failed to download package files. Check your Internet connectino".

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: I download .deb package and it installs on my computer. But when I try to install any package from software center, it gave the same error.